# I have a controller class in which I want to delete the selected records

Tags: exception

but it gives DML exception "`Delete Restricted By Foreign Key Error`"  here I'm unable to find which record is restricted

```
public PageReference deleted() {
    try {
        List < Contact > obj = new List < Contact > ();
        for (ContactWrapper avar: ContactList) {
            if (avar.selected == True) {
                obj.add(avar.acc);
            }
        }
        delete obj;
    } catch (DmlException ex) {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        system.debug(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: public PageReference deleted()    
    {
        try{
        List<Contact> obj = new List<Contact>();
        for(ContactWrapper avar : ContactList )
            {
                if (avar.selected == True)
                    {
                        obj.add(avar.acc);
                    }
            } 
                          
    delete obj; 
  }
  
 catch(DmlException ex){
       

     
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        system.debug(ex);
    }
    return null;
    }

Comment: Please post your apex and vf code

Comment: @satishh you need to check lookup field on contact.

Comment: did you ever figure out what was causing this error? i'm getting it this is the only reference google can find to that particular error message. fyi, i logged a case with salesforce support to explain what that error message means and will post back here with any details

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the exception you'll get an explanation.

Standard objects have several restrictions on deleting certain records with children, i.e. you can't delete an asset associated with a case.

If you look at your exception message you'll see what's happening in your case. To address it you'll need to delete those records first before deleting the contact.